# How to run this Druid SQL query from pydruid using "timeseries"?

Tags: python, sql, database, druid, pydruid

The following is the code in Druid SQL. My goal is to run this code from Python. I'm able to do so using DB API, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with the hydroid function "timeseries" because it would go better with the rest of my code. I haven't been able to get results because I'm not sure how to implement the "Avg" function into timeseries.

Thanks!

```
  SELECT TIME_FLOOR(__time, 'PT1h') AS "__time_time_floor",
       AVG("value"), COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM "database"
WHERE "__time" >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND "device" = 'device_1'AND
      "metric"='metric_1'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY "__time_time_floor" DESC;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
druid_host = "localhost"
druid_port = 8888
druid_path = "/druid/v2/sql"
druid_scheme = "http"
druid_query = """SELECT * FROM wikipedia LIMIT 10"""    
druid_connection = connect(host=druid_host, port=druid_port, path=druid_path, scheme=druid_scheme)
druid_cursor= druid_connection.cursor()
df = pd.DataFrame(druid_cursor.execute(druid_query))
```